# Formatear fecha del español en PHP

Tags: php

tengo un problemilla, y es que me han pasado un csv con una fecha en este formato:

```
09:00:00 - miércoles 30 octubre
```

Hay alguna manera de hacer un parse de esto con un DateTime? Necesito convertirlo a fecha en PHP.

**EDIT**

Intento de pasar a DateTime:

```
$day = \DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s - l d F Y", $item['fecha_inicio']);
```

*Retorna false*

Gracias!!

Comment: ¿A una fecha en qué formato?, por favor considera editar y agregar el formato de salida que esperas obtener

Comment: @Aprendiz El formato de salida es igual, ponle Y-m-d, el caso es convertirlo a objeto DateTime, una vez hecho eso, el formato le pones el que quieras

Comment: No termino de entender, ¿quieres que se vea como: **`YY-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`**?

Comment: Intento crear el Objeto a partir de la fecha esa, mira el edit @Aprendiz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createFromFormat` solamente trabaja con formatos de fecha en inglés. Para otros idiomas se podría utilizar la [extensión internacional de PHP](https://www.php.net/intl), a condición de que la misma esté instalada en tu entorno.

Otra posibilidad sería tratar la cadena, haciendo una conversión a un formato en inglés, para poder pasárselo a `createFromFormat`.

La solución consiste en crear un array que relacione los días en español con los días en inglés, y lo mismo para los meses. Luego separamos la cadena recibida y armamos una cadena usando los valores reemplazados.

#### Código

```
#Mediante el día en español sabremos su equivalente en inglés
$mDays=array ( 
                'domingo'=>'sunday',
                'lunes'=>'monday',
                'martes'=>'tuesday',
                'miércoles'=>'wednesday',
                'jueves'=>'thursday',
                'viernes'=>'friday',
                'sábado'=>'saturday'
             );

#Mediante el mes en español sabremos su equivalente en inglés
$mMonths=array (
                'enero'=>'january',
                'febrero'=>'february',
                'marzo'=>'march',
                'abril'=>'april',
                'mayo'=>'may',
                'junio'=>'june',
                'julio'=>'july',
                'agosto'=>'august',
                'septiembre'=>'september',
                'octubre'=>'october',
                'noviembre'=>'november',
                'diciembre'=>'december'
                );

$strDate="09:00:00 - miércoles 30 octubre";
#Separamos hora y día
$strParts=explode(" - ",$strDate);
#Separamos nombre del día, cifra y mes
$dateParts=explode(" ",$strParts[1]);
#día
$dd=$mDays[strtolower($dateParts[0])];
#mes
$mm=$mMonths[strtolower($dateParts[2])];
#fecha buscando en los arrays
$enDate="$strParts[0] $dd $dateParts[1] $mm";

#that's all folks! :)
$day = \DateTime::createFromFormat("H:i:s l d F", $enDate);
var_dump($day);
```

**Salida de ejemplo:**

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-10-30 09:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!